# How could a query fail to insert data into mysql that is retrieved from WEB?

Tags: mysql, json, insert

I need to insert some data into mysql. I am not sure if I need to check the inputs OR format/strip them before they could be inserted into database fields as results returned from web may contain characters that mysql do not accept(I think). I have trouble with inserting tweets into mysql table. The type of field is varchar.  This is insert statement in php script:

```
$json = $_POST['msg_top'];
      $msg = json_decode($json);
           foreach($msg->entry as $status)
               {
                 $t = $status->content;
                 $query = "INSERT INTO msg2(id,msg,msg_id,depth) VALUES ('','$t','ID','3')";
                 mysql_query($query);
                 if(!mysql_query($query, $dbh))
                 {die('error:' .mysql_error());} 
              }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Where does this fail? This calls for basic debugging

Comment: How could I do basic debugging? The problem for me with testing it is that as it gets data by post from a js script, I check the values in database are they inserted or not. But I do not know how to check if the error occurs data not being POSTed or any problem in this file. Bec there is no data If I just run this to check if it has a problem.

Comment: Well, even if it's from an AJAX request, you can still just return whatever strings you like and view them in [console](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-debugging-with-firebug) of the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very important to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) all values before using them in an SQL command.

```
$json = $_POST['msg_top'];
$msg = json_decode($json);
foreach($msg->entry as $status) {
    $t = mysql_real_escape_string($status->content);
    $query = "INSERT INTO msg2(id,msg,msg_id,depth) VALUES ('','$t','ID','3')";
    mysql_query($query);
    if( !mysql_query($query, $dbh) ) {
        die('error:' .mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Also, other possible issues with your query:

1. If the id field is auto_increment'ing, you don't need it in the field or value list.
2. I may be missing something, but why are you using the string 'ID' for the msg_id field?

As for help troubleshooting this, I'd recommend just appending all of the $query strings to a log file for later inspection. Then, if problems aren't readily apparent, you can just manually try to run the command on the database (ie: maybe via PhpMyAdmin) and check out any error codes from there.